# Issue in self signed certificate

Tags: ssl, https, axis

I am now trying to access the web service via https and to achieve this i have done the below.

I used the below commands to generate the self signed certificate and placed in /conf dir.

```
keytool -genkey -alias localhost -keyalg RSA -validity 365 –keystore server.keystore –storetype JKS
keytool -export -alias localhost –keystore server.keystore -rfc -file public.cert
keytool -import -alias localhost -file public.cert –storetype JKS -keystore server.truststore
```

Below is the server.xml entry

```
<Connector className="org.apache.catalina.connector.http.HttpConnector"
               port="8443" minProcessors="5" maxProcessors="75"
               enableLookups="true"
           acceptCount="10" debug="0" scheme="https" secure="true">
      <Factory className="org.apache.catalina.net.SSLServerSocketFactory"
               keystoreFile="conf/server.keystore"
               keystorePass="changeit"
               truststoreFile="conf/server.truststore"
           truststoreType="JKS" truststorePass="changeit"
               clientAuth="false" protocol="TLS"/>
</Connector>
```

And now i am facing the below error.

```
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
```

However the error is not thrown if i add the below code in the class file accessing the webservice.

```
AxisProperties.setProperty("axis.socketSecureFactory","org.apache.axis.components.net.SunFakeTrustSocketFactory");
```

Could you please guide me in resolving this issue?

Comment: In the very first command you have `-keystore` without mandatory argument. Plus you seem to save server public key certificate into truststore, unless this is a typo.

Comment: @divanov Updated the original command i used cmd, sorry for my mistake. Reg the truststore, i used the command provided, if this is wrong could you please guide me to perform the action correctly? Thanks –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below entry is added in the class file where the call to https would happen and it works like charm. Yet i am not sure why the xml entry is not considered.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "path\\to\\server.keystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "path\\to\\server.truststore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
```

PS: Both xml entry and the class entry is needed else the same error is thrown. I am yet to get a clear picture on this. Maybe someone might explain. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TLS is being set up on two sides: server and client. Each side must have its own key pair saved into a key store. Let's call them `serverKeystore.jks` and `clientKeystore.jks`
Then additional key store is to be created containing only public key. This one is called trust store and used for key authentication. Let's follow the same scheme and save them into `serverTruststore.jks` and `clientTruststore.jks`.

In one way TLS only server key is being authenticated.

- Server must have only `serverKeystore.jks` provisioned in `Connector`.
- Client must have provisioned both `clientKeystore.jks` and `serverTruststore.jks`.

In two way TLS both server and client keys are being authenticated.

- Server must have `serverKeystore.jks` and `clientTruststore.jks` provisioned in `Connector`.
- Client must have provisioned both `clientKeystore.jks` and `serverTruststore.jks`.

Client registers key stores either by specifying Java environment variable with

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="path\\to\\server.keystore"
```

in parameters to command starting JVM, or programmatically in the code with

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "path\\to\\server.keystore");
```

Technically it is possible to use the same key pair both on client and server side as you did. But this compromises the private key, as it is not secret any more.